# Why a protobuf file is larger than its deserialized object in R memory?

Tags: r, serialization, request, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I make some request to an API and I download a large protobuf file containing several messages (around 2.1 GB) and after deserialization (see the code below, using the `DecodeVarint32()` function available from: https://github.com/fkgruber/protobuf_reader) I obtain a very small R object in comparison (<30 MB).
All messages are well deserialized and i get all the data inside.

The data size of the `httr` request content before deserialization = 2.1 GB
[image: data size rg$content]

The data size of the R object after deserialization = 1.5 MB
[image: data size R object]

**How can we explain this large difference?**

***EDIT***:
Here's a reproductible example with a subset of the data. The `rg` object is 1.1 MB and its deserialized `outputlist` (containing two messages) is only 1904 bytes.

[*Link to download the protobuf response object obtained from the request*](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zGmReOrTr2qfmRbrRV0zB6Xev4laqvwo/view?usp=sharing)

[*Link to the .proto file*](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1ht0_ptQFwoGmrGd-hiyRyNM9VuL5TN/view?usp=sharing)

```r
rg = readRDS("rg.RDS")

library(dplyr)
library(RProtoBuf)
readProtoFiles("message2.proto", package = 'RProtoBuf')

alldata = rg$content
n = 1
i = 1
outputlist = list()
while (n < length(alldata)) {
  pos = DecodeVarint32(alldata,as.integer(n))
  clen = pos[[1]]
  n = pos[[2]]
  nend = n + clen - 1
  tmp = alldata[n:nend]
  outputlist[[i]] = read(Spectrum, tmp)
  n = nend + 1
  i = i+1
}
object.size(outputlist)
```

Code of the `DecodeVarint32()` function below:

```
library(bitops)

DecodeVarint32 = function(buffer, pos){
  mask = (2 ^ 32 - 1)
  result = 0 %>% as.raw
  shift = 0
  while(TRUE){
    b = buffer[pos]
    result = bitOr(as.numeric(result),
                   bitShiftL(
                     bitAnd(as.numeric(b), as.numeric(0x7f)),
                     shift))
    pos = pos + 1
    if(!bitAnd(b,0x80)){
      result = bitAnd(result,mask)
      result = as.integer(result)
      return(list(result, pos))
    }
    shift = shift + 7
    if(shift >= 64){
      stop("Too  many bytes when decoding varint")
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the deserialized data in your `outputlist` is correct and full when compared to some other protobuf decoder? Because the obvious answer would that your code has a bug and only deserializes part of the data.

Comment: What other protobuf decoder do you suggest? I only used the one shown in the example.

Comment: Yes i checked, all my data is ok. Nevertheless, i just found that the deserialized data contained in the protobuf message object is indeed **larger** than the whole binary data, while the message object itself  is very small (as returned by object.size()). The thing is that we have to measure the size of each individual field of the message. Why can't we get the full size of the message ?

Comment: The deserialized message shows `@ pointer:<externalptr>` in the environment, could it explain that we don't get the size of the data it contains?